# Failed to loop for date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use a loop which will go form   StartDateTime  to EndDateTime .But failed.Additionally how can I increase vale in hour or second section?

```
declare 
StartDateTime date := timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
EndDateTime   date := timestamp '2017-12-31 23:59:59';

begin

 FOR D IN StartDateTime ..EndDateTime   LOOP 

 dbms_output.put_line(StartDateTime);

END LOOP ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` Notation works only for Numbers. You can use a loop like this for Dates.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    startdatetime   DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
    enddatetime     DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
BEGIN    
    FOR d  IN 0..(enddatetime-startdatetime-1)
   LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(startdatetime + d);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

This one uses SQL.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    startdatetime   DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
    enddatetime     DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
BEGIN
    FOR d IN (
        SELECT
            startdatetime + level - 1 dt
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            level <= enddatetime - startdatetime + 1
    ) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(d.dt);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**Note:** it is always better to use `TO_DATE` with proper format when you are assigning a date string than implicit `TIMESTAMP` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Add a fraction of days or an `INTERVAL '1' SECOND` literal to your date (or dynamically generated interval using `NUMTODSINTERVAL( amount, units )`:

```
DECLARE 
  StartDateTime DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
  EndDateTime   DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
BEGIN
  FOR d IN 0 .. ( EndDateTime - StartTime ) * 24  LOOP 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( StartDateTime + NUMTODSINTERVAL( d, 'HOUR' ) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or

```
DECLARE 
  StartDateTime DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
  EndDateTime   DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
BEGIN
  FOR d IN 0 .. ( EndDateTime - StartTime ) * 24  LOOP 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( StartDateTime + INTERVAL '1' HOUR * d );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or

```
DECLARE 
  StartDateTime DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
  EndDateTime   DATE := TIMESTAMP '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
BEGIN
  FOR d IN 0 .. ( EndDateTime - StartTime ) * 24  LOOP 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( StartDateTime + d / 24 );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```